# Matching 2D image pixels in corresponding 3D point cloud

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, ros, point-cloud-library

I want to match pixels of calibrated 3D lidar and 2D camera data. I will use this to train a network. Can this be considered as labeled data with this matching? If it is, is there anyone to help me to achive this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On a high level, assuming you have some transformation (rotation/translation) between your camera and your lidar, and the calibration matrix of the camera, you have a 3D image and a 2D projection of it. 
That is, if you project the 3D pointcloud onto the the image plane of the camera, you will have a `(x,y)_camera` (point in camera frame) for every `(RGB)D_world == (x,y,z)_world)` point.

Whether this is helpful to train on depends on what you're trying to achieve; if you're trying to find where the camera is or calibrate it, given (RGB)D data and image(s), that could be done better with a Perspective-n point algorithm (the lidar could make it easier, perhaps, if it built up a "real" view of the world to compare against). Whether it would be considered labeled data, depends on how you are trying to label it. They both say very similar things.

Comment: Naively, I'd think you're either trying to train depth perception to a camera, or color perception to a depth-only lidar. Or just localization/calibration?